# Is there any way to find out the extensions of the Images stored in a database as binary data?

Tags: java, android, sql-server

I have to get Product details including Product Image(binary data) from MSSQL database and store it locally on Android device as image files, I don't know the type of the Images. I think when we're storing Images as files its extension matters, if it matters is there any way to find out the Image Extensions?

Thanks and regards.

Comment: Matters for what? Bitmap.decode? No... And yes, it is possible to get mime type after reading few first bytes, as it is common for different files format to put some magic bytes there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [BitmapFactory.Options.outMimeType](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#outMimeType) for that.
It will contain string like `image/png` or `image/jpg` after your image is decoded.

Sample:

```
InputStream in = getAssets().open("image.file");
BitmapFactory.Options opts = new BitmapFactory.Options();
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, opts);
Log.d(TAG, "Mime type: " + opts.outMimeType);
```

In my case it writes in log:

> 05-31 15:20:34.131: D/Test(3803): Mime type: image/jpeg